# Custom Generics explanation

Tags: java, generics, interface, jakarta-ee

Please explain the custom 'T' in the java interface. It is using generics here and of type 'T' i suppose. Then where is the type 'T' defined?

```
  public interface TemplateBuilder<T extends TemplateBuilder>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

T is not an actual class. It is determined at compile time depending on the usage of your class TemplateBuilder. Just think of it as a place holder for various possible types, one of which is 'chosen' depending on your circumstances.

For a simpler example, look at the following (adapted from Java's tutorial):

Imagine you want to declare a class Box, which can take a specific type (of the object to hold inside the box), but you wish to reuse this in various circumstances to hold various different types.

So instead of fixing the actual type the Box can take, you declare it as follows:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private T t; // T stands for "Type"          

    public void set(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }
}
```

When you use it, you then do something like:

```
Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
```

Whats the whole point you might ask? Why not make Box take an Object?

In fact before Java 1.5 this was not possible. This was introduced to have further type-safety in these situations, and was adopted in the Collections framework.

The whole point is that without this mechanism, if instead it used Object, you can't force a specific instance of your Box to hold only Integers. On the other hand, if you made it use specifically Integers, you can't reuse your Box for String, or other objects, and you would need to create another type of Box class.

Before Java 1.5, objects like ArrayList took plain Objects, however there were often cases of type safety broken at runtime, because the program is assuming a list of Integer objects and by mistake somewhere a String is inserted. Generics (through this magic T) force types without restricting what they might be.

In your case `T extends TemplateBuilder` is going one step further and stating that whatever T is, it must be a class that extends TemplateBuilder. If that wasn't there, it would be any class that extends Object (the universal base class of Java).

Comment: Is `IntegerBox` a type or a typo?

Answer (score 1):

T is any `Object` that extends from `TemplateBuilder`

T means any Object. for example

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

here T can be `Integer`, `String` ...

and `<T extends A>` means any `Object T` extends from `A`

Answer (score 1):

This type is defined when implementing the interface, i.e.

```
class StringBuilder implements TemplateBuilder<StringBuilder> {}
```

BTW, see class Enum (the base class of all enums).

Answer (score 0):

**My Custom Generics Explanation**

Backgorund:

1. Custom generics are used invariably with data structures e.g. when managing(storing/retrieving) lists of "things"
2. You **do not** need to do your own **type checking** in order for the code to compile as custom generics incorporates the principles of polymorphism.
3. However, in contrast to the "traditional" OO principles of polymorphism, a class can store a list of things **without** having any **relationship** with the "thing(s)" it is storing (The Fundamental Principle of OO where A is a super class of B class is not required)
4. You do not make separate subclasses for every possible kind of class of "things" you wish to store.

**Example 1**

As an example consider the following two classes below which are **unrelated**. This is a very primitive example but nonetheless gives an outline of the principles of custom generics:

```
/**
 *
 * Class A is a Custom Generic class that can be 'typed'
 * to any kind of class using diamond 'T' syntax. 
 * 
 */

class A<T> 
{   
  // The instance variable of the object type 'T' known at run time
  T theI;

  // The constructor passing the object type 'T' 
  A(T anI)
  {
    this.theI = anI;
  }

  // Method to return the object 'T'
  T getT()
  {
    return theI;
  }
}
```

Below is the class B which is unrelated to class A i.e. B does not extend A:

```
/**
*
* Simple class which overrides the toString()
* method from Object's class toString() method 
* 
*/
class B 
{

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "B Object";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A<B> a = new A<>(new B());

    System.out.println(a.getT());        
  }
}
```

In Main method of class B above:

a.getT() returns the object 'T' which in this example is of type 'B' (This is an example of polymorphism).

a.getT() returns the object 'T', object instance C's method toString() gets IMPLICITLY called, as it is overriding Object's toString() method and prints "B Object".

The interesting aspect to note about Custom Generics and polymorphism is that:

In the context of custom generics, there are **no constraints for a relationship** among classes in order to execute polymorphism

e.g. Class B is **unrelated** to A above i.e class B **DOES not extend** A.

In "*traditional*" object orientated polymorphism principles, there is invariably a requirement constraint for classes to be related in some way. However, this is not required in custom generics.

**Example 2**

```
public interface TemplateBuilder<T extends TemplateBuilder>
```

The above means that TemplateBuilder interface can be ***typed*** to any class that **extends** TemplateBuilder.

Let's assume SomeClass extends TemplateBuilder then the following is fine:

```
TemplateBuilder<SomeClass> tbRef = ... 
/* Using an Anonymous Inner Class reference to interface TemplateBuilder<SomeClass> */
```

or

```
TemplateBuilder<SomeClass> tbRef = .... /*  Referencing a concrete class 
that implements TemplateBuilder */
```